# Is the storyboard property an attribute of UIViewController?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

This question was raised in another post and I couldn't them to expound on what they meant.  I was under the notion that the storyboard is an attribute of UIViewController because Apple's reference doc says var storyboard in the area that reads "Interacting with Storyboards and Segues".  [Apple UIViewController reference doc](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller) One of the comments read "The storyboard isn't a property or an attribute of either UIViewController" and I hoped they would expound on this.  Could anyone help because now I am confused on if I'm reading or utilizing the reference docs correctly.

The initial question is here: [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50088212/how-come-when-downcasting-i-dont-have-to-use-an-initializer-of-itemstableviewco/50088270?noredirect=1#comment87193002_50088270)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the documentation, the definition states:

> `var storyboard: UIStoryboard?`
>
> > The storyboard from which the view controller originated.

You're correct in thinking that `var storyboard` is a property of `UIViewController`. The reason for your confusion is that your mental model is assuming that because `UIViewController` has a reference to `storyboard`, it must **own** it. `storyboard` is simply a reference to the storyboard that **loaded** your `UIViewController`. It should be looked at as more of a bottom-up relationship rather than top-down.

In practice, as a `UIViewController`, a common use case is to ask your `storyboard` to instantiate other UIViewControllers, which we can then present:

```
let viewControllerToPresent = storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "presentedController")
present(viewControllerToPresent, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The `UIViewController` class definitely has a [storyboard property](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621399-storyboard).

Your other question is asking about the instantiation and initialisation of the initial view controller. In the context of that question, what I believe was meant is that the `UIViewController` class does not have a storyboard attribute that it somehow knows *before an instance is instantiated* that lets it instantiate itself from a storyboard.

Rather, the `UIStoryboard` *sets the `storyboard` property* on the `UIViewController` instance after it has created it. This is necessary for segues to work.

Note that the `storyboard` property is an optional, and it won't have a value if the instance wasn't created by a storyboard.